# Rails and Existing Postgres Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

What are the best practices in case you want to build a Rails project that uses an existing Database?

in my case the postgres database living on a remote machine that runs a docker instance with postgres has a database with a table `stake_address`.

Now I have created a model in Rail:

```rb
class StakeAddress < ApplicationRecord
end
```

in `rails console`:

```
2.6.1 :001 > StakeAddress.all
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "stake_addresses" does not exist)
LINE 1: SELECT "stake_addresses".* FROM "stake_addresses" LIMIT $1
                                        ^
```

is there a way to avoid Rails to look for a pluralised table?
I suppose there are going to be many other problems like this, so I was wondering if this is common practice, or if is something out of the world that is highly recommended to avoid?

Also I guess I don't need migrations, because the database is already created. Is that going to cause problems down the line?

My idea is that I will be able to connect to two databases, one read-only already existing and the other one where I can put my own models as Users. But will they be able to create association cross databases?

Perhaps Rails isn't the best framework for this type of work? Is what I am learning during a bootcamp, but perhaps I should switch to more flexible environments?

Comment: As a solution to your first problem just add `self.table_name = 'stake_address'` to your model file. And no you don't need migrations.

Comment: I would use postgres_fdw and link your existing database into the rails specific database.  Then your queries can be run against both databases as if they are one.  I don't think your can add foreign keys but most things should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are not too many tables, I would also recommend what @eyeslandic suggests and manually override the table names in the models that need it.

```
self.table_name = 'stake_address'
```

If there are many tables, you’d be better off in the long run if you renamed them. [You can do this safely in production with something like LHM](https://github.com/soundcloud/lhm#table-rename-strategies).